# How to detect touch outside (empty space) - cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is my code for detect that if touch on a specific sprite

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

for(CCSprite *sprite in shapeArray)
{

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, location))
    {
        //There is a sprite that is touched
         mSpriteOnHand = sprite;
        currentPoint = mSpriteOnHand.position;

        break;
    } 
    //This part didn't work
    else
    {
      NSLog(@"Touch outside);
    }
}
```

}

Now I want to detect if touch is outside(not on any sprite or empty space) but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Are you asking if the touch is not on the screen? Or if the touch just isn't on a sprite?

Comment: what you say seems a little wierd, if you consider the for you have done, assuming that the array has at least 2 elements in it, when the method calls the touch, unless you do not press always the first item in the array , the else statement is called n times, until it finds the sprite that has been touched. So I have to ask, are you sure that the for functions and even the if functions works properly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your touches are working, than I think adding a BOOL and then an if statement outside the for loop, like this will work.

```
BOOL itemFound = NO;
for(CCSprite *sprite in shapeArray)
{

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, location))
    {
    //There is a sprite that is touched
        mSpriteOnHand = sprite;
        currentPoint = mSpriteOnHand.position;
        NSLog(@"item TOUCHED");
        itemFound = YES;
        break;
    } 
}

if (itemFound == NO)
{
     NSLog(@"Touch outside");
}
```